# Запросы MS SQL что не так сделал

Tags: sql-server

Исправленный вариант

```
CREATE DATABASE SHOPBD
COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
GO
--Заполнение полей
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR_BOOK
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    authorName NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE TYPE_BOOK
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    typeName NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
);


CREATE TABLE CATEGORY_BOOK
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    categoryName NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
);

-- Информация о книге
CREATE TABLE BOOK_NAME
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name_book_fild NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    type_book_id INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TYPE_BOOK(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- ID Авторав и книг
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR_BOOK_ID
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    INDEX FK_AUTHOR_BOOK_idx(authorID),
    authorID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AUTHOR_BOOK(id)
    INDEX FK_BOOK_NAME_idx(bookID),
    bookID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BOOK_NAME(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- ID категорий и книг
CREATE TABLE CATEGORYIES
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,

    INDEX FK_CATEGORY_BOOK_idx(categoryID),
    categoryID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CATEGORY_BOOK(id)

    INDEX FK_BOOK_NAME_idx(bookID),
    bookID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BOOK_NAME(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Исправил на сколько понял! Правильно или нет?

Comment: вы условия соединения не задали, поэтому получили полное декартово произведение таблиц. необходимо добавить where с указанием какие поля таблиц должны между собой совпадать в результирующем наборе. т.е. буквально `where name_book2.author_id = author.id`

Comment: @Mike А, не подскажете как правильно?  Where я тоже пробовал по разному но так и не чего не получилось.

Comment: И да, в таком виде как вы хотите вы в принципе ничего не получите. количество колонок в результирующем наборе задается фразой select и меняться динамически не может. и так как у вас на выходе только 1 колонка author_id то и в результате у вас будет по отдельной строке на каждого автора, с единственным значением в этом поле. максимум что можно сделать, это объединить авторов например через запятую. но в MS SQL это довольно не тривиальная задача https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477743/listagg-in-sqlserver

Comment: @Mike А, как правильно переделать? Мне структуру переделать нужно? Извиняюсь, это наверное очевидные вопросы но я только начал изучение немного путаюсь что и куда!

Comment: ничего переделывать не надо. надо просто принять как данность и _не хотеть_ получить в одной строке сразу список. потому SQL для этого не предназначен. Если вам в программе хочется вывести список авторов в строку, то вам надо уже в той программе получить набор строк из mysql, отсортированный например по книге и самому развернуть авторов в горизонталь, начиная новую строку на выводе, только если в очередной строке из БД книга не совпадает с той, что была в предыдущей. Ну либо, если списка через запятую вам достаточно использовать "for xml" как по приведенной выше ссылке

Comment: @Mike Так в коде всё правильно сделано с точки зрения структуры. Если мне нужно что бы база давала ответ на вопрос (Какие произведения написал писатель?) к примеру, то всё верно. Он мне выдаст к примеру (1 1) первое это id автора 1 к примеру ,а второе id произведения 1 то есть одно?

Comment: на счет "все правильно" я погорячился. не присматривался к структуре. name_book2 не должна существовать. Если у книги несколько авторов (и у автора несколько книг) от делается таблица из 2х полей: id-автора, id-книги. Если у книги может быть несколько категорий (а в одной категории несколько книг), то делается еще одна таблица, опять же из двух полей: id-книги, id-категории. Не знаю что такое type_book, но если предположить, что у одной книги только один тип, то в самой таблице name_book заводиться поле type_id

Comment: @Mike  А, не подскажете как правильно связи настроить (кодом)

Comment: @Mike ну я про вторичные ключи! Или у меня там всё правильно сделано?

Comment: вот в тех таблицах про которые я писал выше связи будут написаны так же как у вас сейчас в book2

Comment: @Mike спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Comment: @Mike под id-книги ты имеешь ввиду ссылку на id name_book? правильно я понял или нужно ещё одну таблицу сделать Book&

Comment: ссылку на id в name_book

Comment: @Mike Я исправил! Глянь пожалуйста! Правильно я понял или нет!

Comment: Вы бы сказали, какова постановка задачи. верны ли мои догадки, что категорий у книги может быть несколько а тип только один

Comment: @Mike Да! Тип это (учебник или справочник или пособие) имеется ввиду. Я сам путаюсь. Категории (жанры) у книги может быть несколько так же как и авторов несколько у одной книге.

Comment: @Mike задача такая! (Какие произведения написал писатель?
-        Какие произведения входят в указанную категории?
-        Кто автор или авторы указанного произведения?
-        В каких жанрах писатель создавал произведения?
) на такие вопросы должна отвечать база

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается структуры, то я бы сделал так:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR_BOOK
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    authorName NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE TYPE_BOOK
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    typeName NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
);


CREATE TABLE CATEGORY_BOOK
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    categoryName NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
);

-- Информация о книге
CREATE TABLE BOOK_NAME
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name_book_fild NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    type_book_id INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TYPE_BOOK(id)
);

-- ID Авторав и книг
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR_BOOK_ID
(
    bookID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BOOK_NAME(id),
    authorID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AUTHOR_BOOK(id),
    CONSTRAINT AUTHOR_BOOK_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY (bookID, authorID),
    INDEX FK_AUTHOR_BOOK_idx(authorID),
);

-- ID категорий и книг
CREATE TABLE CATEGORYIES
(
    bookID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES BOOK_NAME(id),
    categoryID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CATEGORY_BOOK(id),
    CONSTRAINT CATEGORYIES_PK PRIMARY KEY (bookID, categoryID),
    INDEX FK_CATEGORY_BOOK_idx(categoryID),
)
```

В таблицах обеспечивающих связь многие ко многим собственный ID в таблице не нужен. Потому как в любом случае необходим уникальный ключ, содержащий два поля связи. Например автора и книгу, потому что один автор не может два раза написать одну и ту же книгу. Первичный ключ заодно уникальный, по этому используем его. В таком случае индекс по bookID так же не нужен, так как это поле первое в первичном ключе и поиск будет работать по нему.

Кроме того bookID вынесен первым в составе первичного ключа в предположении, что задача показа всех авторов или всех категорий каждой книги чаще, чем поиск всех книг одной категории (одного автора). Опять же из предположения, что даже при выводе книг одной категории наверняка потребуется около каждой из них написать все категории к которой она принадлежит.

Все `ON DELETE NO ACTION` и `ON UPDATE CASCADE` убраны, потому что если их писать, то у каждого foreign отдельно. И такое поведение как обновление ID при изменении в основной таблице не имеет смысла, так как поля identity менять все равно нельзя. И вообще эти возможности следует использовать только в случае когда вы точно знаете, зачем это делаете. В большинстве случаев они опасны и поведение по умолчанию - наилучшее. Кстати `NO ACTION` является поведением по умолчанию, поэтому его так же указывать нет особого смысла.

Comment: Спасибо! Не мог бы объяснить что делает `CONSTRAINT` Я его не проходил ещё. Что бы ещё больше не запутаться.

Comment: И последний вопрос!!! По поводу заполнения полей через INSERT Заполнять же все таблицы нужно будет?

Comment: @j.Atisto Это просто ключевое слово. Если PRIMARY KEY состоит из одной колонки, то мы его пишем около этой самой колонки и все. При этом БД сама назначает первичному ключу имя (у него есть имя). Когда же мы делаем первичный ключ состоящий из нескольких колонок, то тут мы уже обязаны сами дать ему имя и синтаксис его объявления именно таков, начиная со слова CONSTRAINT (в переводе "ограничение")

Comment: @j.Atisto Да, конечно все, по очереди. Т.е. нам в интерфейсе скажем ввели название книги и авторов. Мы создаем сначала книгу, потом авторов (или требуем их заводить заранее, это смотря как реализовать интерфейс) и после того как записи и книги и авторов есть в БД создаем записи в связующей таблице, ставя туда соответствующие ID

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответы! И особенно за объяснение!!!

Comment: Я сильно извиняюсь! Как записывать в таблицу AUTHOR_BOOK_ID или CATEGORYIES `INSERT INTO AUTHOR_BOOK_ID (bookID, authrID)
VALUES 
(select id from BOOK_NAME where name_book_fild = 'Град обречённый'),
(select id from AUTHOR_BOOK where authorName = 'Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие')` ну шо то не работает! Всё остальное как по маслу А, здесь не в какую!Вроде принцип такой же.Но не работает! Не подскажешь!

Comment: @j.Atisto все значения values должны быть в одних скобках, так что `... values( ( select ...) , (select ...) )` А вообще в большинстве случаев во время работы программы она и так знает id и ей не надо еще раз искать их по именам

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать!